# Custom control is not visible in Xcode designer

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I try to create custom control and use it to create views in Xcode designer. My new created custom control meet all the requirements from this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/ios-designable-controls-overview.

MyCustomControl.cs

```
[Register("MyCustomControl"), DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public class MyCustomControl : UIView
{
    public MyCustomControl(IntPtr intPtr) : base(intPtr)
    {

    }
}
```

MyCustomControl.xib

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="18122" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="18093"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="MyCustomControl"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="1">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="168"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="launch_image.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mzD-dG-Liz">
                    <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="128" height="128"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemGreenColor"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="PWL-tY-GGw"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="128" id="pzM-Pd-W9T"/>
                    </constraints>
                </imageView>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aut-I9-LZ3">
                    <rect key="frame" x="156" y="20" width="238" height="128"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="30"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="mzD-dG-Liz" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="1" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="0eJ-7I-8oa"/>
                <constraint firstItem="aut-I9-LZ3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="mzD-dG-Liz" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="2WT-9N-Ahk"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="aut-I9-LZ3" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="4e9-Uy-yd0"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="aut-I9-LZ3" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="AMI-iw-m0b"/>
                <constraint firstItem="aut-I9-LZ3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="1" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="DXk-Cr-Rua"/>
                <constraint firstItem="mzD-dG-Liz" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="1" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="HUw-sB-TJ2"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="mzD-dG-Liz" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="ZcF-qS-fei"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-18.840579710144929" y="-265.84821428571428"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="launch_image.png" width="420" height="420"/>
        <systemColor name="systemGreenColor">
            <color red="0.20392156862745098" green="0.7803921568627451" blue="0.34901960784313724" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

I have rebuild project, create another custom view to see MyCustomView appears in Xcode designer but I can't see it. Is there something I have forgotten?

Visual Studio for Mac 8.9.9 
Xcode 12.5

Comment: Not clear what you need. You want to show your custom view in Xcode designer when you using Xcode to create a view?

Comment: Yest, I want to be able to drag and drop my custom control when i create new view using Xcode designer.

Comment: Normally, we use a View to host the "custom control". You can refer to [Render and inspect your custom views](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.3/#/devf60c1c514?). About show custom control in Object library, refer the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079501/how-to-add-custom-controls-in-interface-builder-xcode).

Comment: Ok i tried to do it this way but my custom control is blank. I added a host view and set custom class to MyCustomControl. When i start the application my custom control is blank. How to show in this host view MyCustomControl which is designed in MyCustomControl.xib?